# Ext.menu.Menu positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I'm trying to line up a menu that I've created using `Ext.menu.Menu`.  As you can see below, the menu is displayed **1 pixel** to the right of its parent.

[image: The menu isn't quite right]

What's the best way to get this perfectly aligned?.  I've looked into `getPostion()` and `setPosition()` briefly and I'm not sure that's the correct way to do this.

My menu code is pretty basic:

```
var userMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
    id: 'userMenu',
    width: 120,
    height: 70,
    items: [
        {
            text: 'My Settings',
            handler: settingsHandler                    
        },
        {
            text: 'Sign out',
            handler: signoutHandler         
        }   
        ]
    });     

       var menuHandler = function(e) { 
            userMenu.show('parent-menu');    
       }; 

       Ext.get('parent-menu').on('click',menuHandler);
```

Is there anything that I can add here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use the `userMenu` object?

Comment: That's odd. What browser are you seeing this in? If it's IE, did you set your doctype?

Comment: Seeing the same thing in FF4, IE9, Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, was able to use jQuery after the menu is shown to move it:

```
        var menuLeft = $('#userMenu').position().left;
        $('#userMenu').css('left',(menuLeft-1)+"px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why call the `show` method?
You could just do the following presuming your Menu is on a toolbar.

```
var userMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
  id: 'userMenu',
  width: 120,
  height: 70,
  items: [
    {
        text: 'My Settings',
        handler: settingsHandler                    
    },
    {
        text: 'Sign out',
        handler: signoutHandler         
    }   
  ]
});

    /*Define a toolbar */
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Menu',
        menu: userMenu /*no need to call userMenu.show()*/
    }]
```